# Topic models and distributional hypothesis

Tags: machine-learning, probability, topic-models, word-embeddings

Topic models are a popular way to uncover the topics that are assumed to have generated the documents of a collection. Latent Semantic Analysis (LSA) uses singular value decomposition to approximate the term-document and it is discussed to be a computational model that implements the distributional hypothesis ("you should know a word by the company it keeps"). The different models to derive word embeddings also belong at this category.

Could we say the same for Latent Dirichlet Allocation (LDA) that has a complete generative story and clear probabilistic undergrounds? Are you aware of any resources that cover this?

Comment: I wonder if you've intending a more in-depth question than you've expressed here. The straightforward answer is, "Yes, absolutely." (The first line of the wiki entry on LDA reads, "In natural language processing, latent Dirichlet allocation (LDA) is a generative statistical model that allows sets of observations to be explained by unobserved groups that explain why some parts of the data are similar.") And, the generative model for LDA is fully covered in the paper introducing it. Is this the full extent of your question, or is there something more to it?

Comment: there has been a lot of buzz about how word embeddings models like cbow/skipgram/etc "implement" models of the distributional hypothesis and ofter it is in the first paragraphs of those papers. Although I also feel the same about LDA, it has never occurred to me to read a sentence that states that. So I am wondering, why so and whether I am missing anything..